# Accessing deduced method calls with auto keyword from header file

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

Take the following class:

**BasicOperations.h**

```
template<typename T1>
class BasicOperations
{
    private:
        T1 num;

    public:
        template<typename T1, typename T2>
        BasicOperations() : num(0) {}

        template<typename T1, typename T2> 
        auto addition(T1 num1, T2 num2) -> decltype(T1 + T2) const { return num1 + num2; }
}
```

I have begun using `auto` and from my research found that this is how to declare the function `addition` as listed in the above code.

However, when I try to call the method in my `Main()`, I cannot figure out the syntax to properly call addition... I have open ended questions, but what exactly is wrong with/ how exactly do I syntactically call the `addition` function from my main...

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BasicOperations.h"

int main()
{
    int x = 10, y = 5;
    BasicOperations<int> t(int, int);

    //std::cout << t.addition( x, y ) << '\n'; Error: expression must have class type
}
```

Comment: Please explain downvotes.

Comment: Is the only error you get on the `cout` statement?  Trying to run you code on ideone [fails](https://ideone.com/pEs3sB)

Comment: `BasicOperations<int> t(int, int);` - this is meaningless.

Comment: @ecatmur, I didn't understand how to declare the object or use the method with the `BasicOperations<int> t;` @Ediac pointed out quite well in his answer exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main, this `BasicOperations<int> t(int, int);` as said by another user, is meaningless. When using the debugger, it showed as a function declaration, instead of its intended purpose as constructor. Even though local functions can't be defined, they can still be declared. So even though `t` exists, it is a function and therefore in `t.addition()` it can't recognize `t` as an object of class `BasicOperations` that contains the method `addition`.

Quick fix:

```
template<typename T1>
class BasicOperations
{
    private:
        T1 num;

    public:
        //template<typename T1, typename T2>
        BasicOperations() : num(0) {}

        template<typename T1, typename T2> 
        auto addition(T1 num1, T2 num2) -> decltype(num1 + num2) const { return num1 + num2; }
};

int main()
{
    int x = 10, y = 5;
    BasicOperations<int> t;

    std::cout << t.addition( x, y ) << '\n'; 
    return 0;
}
```

Eliminate `template<typename T1, typename T2>` above default constructor. Also in `-> decltype(T1 + T2)` should be changed to `-> decltype(num1 + num2)`.

When using template constructors, there is no way to explicitly specify the template arguments when calling a constructor template. This means that one cannot write:

`BasicOperations<int> t<int,int>();`

Instead, the types of the templates must be deduced through argument deduction. However, the constructor in the code takes no arguments, that is why `BasicOperations<int> t(int,int);` is read as a function declaration instead.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I wanted to know how to declare it and then use it in a `cout` statement.